# Finding all matches between pairs of conditions in Neo4j using Cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

We have the need to create a report on common sources for each type of a particular node, to explain:
Consider the Type of the Node to be node.type = ["Apple","Windows","Linux","Other"] and the relationships to be of the form

> (source:ANode)-[r:ConnectedTo]->(target:ANode)

Thus, the sources for each type will be:

```
match (source:ANode)-[r:ConnectedTo]->(target:ANode)
return distinct target.type, source.name
```

We need to determine duplicate sources for each pair-wise combination of types, thus, the duplicate sources between "Apple" and "Windows", between "Windows" and "Linux", etc.

I've tried the following, but it seems to work only for the first pair combination:

```
match (source:ANode)-[r:ConnectedTo]->(target:ANode)
where target.type="Apple"
return distinct target.type, source.name
UNION
match (source:ANode)-[r:ConnectedTo]->(target:ANode)
where target.type="Windows"
return distinct target.type, source.name
```

I can already determine common sources between any two systems using code like:

```
Match (node1:ANode)<-[:ConnectsTo]-(src)-[:ConnectsTo]->(node2:ANo‌​de) 
where ID(node1)<ID(node2) 
return node1.type,node1.name,node2.type,node2.name,src.name
```

I can't see how to go from this to the end objective.

I don't think this is the right approach as the number of types could be a lot more than 2-3. Please help with a more elegant approach

Answer (score 1):

[EDITED]

You can use [aggregation](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/aggregating/) to get a collection of distinct source names for each source/target type pair:

```
MATCH (source:ANode)-[r:ConnectedTo]->(target:ANode)
RETURN
  source.type AS sourceType,
  target.type AS targetType,
  COLLECT(DISTINCT source.name) AS sourceNames;
```

Comment: While this does return the sources for each type, I am looking for the common sources between types. 

I can already determine common sources between any two systems using code like:

Match (node1:ANode)<-[:ConnectsTo]-(src)-[:ConnectsTo]->(node2:ANode)
where ID(node1)<ID(node2) 
return node1.type,node1.name,node2.type,node2.name,src.name

I can't see how to go from this to the end objective

Comment: Not sure I correctly understand what you want, but I have edited my answer to show how to get a collection of distinct source names for each source/target type pair.

Comment: Here's the solution I went with:

Comment: Here's the solution I went with:

`code` MATCH (target2:ANode)<-[rel2:ConnectedTo]-(source:ANode)-[rel1:ConnectedTo]->(target1:ANode)
WHERE ID(target1)<>ID(target2) 
return target1.type, count(distinct source) order by target1.type `code`

This produces a matrix of pairs of types with the corresponding common sources.